# What's the best way to create variables that are available to every single URL on my site, based on node id or taxonomy id?

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, theming, configuration

On Drupal site A we have a bunch of links to non-Drupal site B. For marketing and tracking purposes all these links have a different URL variable appended to them, so that when a user registers on site B we can determine where on site A they came from.

At the moment I use **page.tpl.php** to create the variable (`$forceCode`) but it now transpires I need this variable to be available to **node.tpl.php** too, and I feel like there must be a less hacky and more universal way of doing this, probably using a preprocess function in **template.php** that right now seems beyond my comprehension level.

**PLAIN LANGUAGE EXPLANATION**

`$specialPages` is an array of node IDs that need a special code.
`$specialFolders` is an array of taxonomy IDs that need a special code.

- If the current node ID matches any in the `nid` array, I set the variable accordingly.
- If not then I get the category (taxonomy) of the current node, or if the current page is a taxonomy term itself then use its own `tid`.

  - Then using this taxonomy ID I get all other `tid`s that are parents of that `tid`.
  - Then I look for matches of any of these taxonomy IDs in my array of special `tid`s in order to set the variable.
- If the current page has not matched any of my special nodes or taxonomies, the variable remains its default value.

**ACTUAL CODE**

```
// we later restrict our parent taxonomy search to certain types but it's not strictly necessary
$contentTypes = array("article","advpoll","event");

$specialFolders = array(
    276 => "events",
    292 => "free-dating",
    498 => "date-explorer"
);
$specialPages = array(
    22 => "reviews",
    86 => "texting"
);

$forceCode = "default";

// check for specific page first
if (@array_key_exists($node->nid,$specialPages)){
    $forceCode = $specialPages[$node->nid];
} else {
    // there was no entry for this nid, let's check parent terms
    $parentTerms = array();
    $hasParents = false;
    if (arg(0) == "taxonomy") $hasParents = arg(2);
    if (@in_array($node->type,$contentTypes)) {
        $category = field_view_field('node', node_load($node->nid), 'field_category');
        $hasParents = $category['#items'][0]['tid'];
    }
    if ($hasParents !== false) {
        $parents = taxonomy_get_parents_all($hasParents);
        foreach ($parents as $term){
            $parentTerms[] = $term->tid;
        }
    }

    foreach ($parentTerms as $tid){
        if (array_key_exists($tid,$specialFolders)){
            $forceCode = $specialFolders[$tid];
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the generic [`hook_preprocess()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7) perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps Clive - I've tried messing with it for an hour since you said that but not got far. I've tried:

    `function hook_preprocess(&$variables, $hook){
      $variables['myNewVar'] = "anything";
    }`

has not lead to me being able to access $myNewVar from either page.tpl.php or node.tpl.php on any type of page. Also tried by prefixing function with themename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a very satisfactory solution using `function matchtheme_preprocess(&$variables, $hook)` which will always supply variables to page and node templates.

The more complicated bit was finding an appropriate way to get this function to collect the data I need (nid or tid) properly regardless of whether it was the page or node template making the call.

Essentially (this is the cut down version) I just did this:

```
if ($hook == "page"){
    // supplies variables to page.tpl.php
    // the page template can cover anything, including a node and taxonomy
    if (arg(0) == "node"){
        $nidToCheck = arg(1);           
    } else if (arg(0) == "taxonomy"){
        // already a taxonomy page, the term id is the category
        $hasParents = arg(2);
    }
} else if ($hook == "node"){
    // supplies variables to node.tpl.php
    $nidToCheck = $variables['elements']['#node']->nid;
}
```

From there `if ($nidToCheck)` allows me to use the `nid` to generate `$hasParents` for nodes, and then I can move on handling all nodes and taxonomy terms to do what I want (all this bit is essentially the same as in my question).

Finally I feed back to the template an array of variables in much the same way as they were set before.

So glad to have this sorted as it caused quite a headache. Would love to hear whether or not this is an efficient or clever way of dealing with it. The most obvious issue to me is that the array of variables (and of course the whole function) will get run twice on node pages - once for the page template and once for the node template - which is a touch inefficent. I guess I could contain the whole thing in an `if (!isset...`